# Populating an RSS feed with full post content?

Tags: best-practice, rss

I'm using Matrix to give loads of flexibility with blog posts, but it means things aren't as simple when it comes to RSS than if just using a single field called *Body*.

How is everyone else dealing with this?

EDIT: As Christian points out, I'm party asking what is best practice for RSS feeds. But I'm also exploring the extra flexibility or complexibility offered by using Matrix for blog post content. Best practice is constantly evolving, and I think it quite possible best practice for creating an RSS feed using Craft may turn out to be different best practice to feeds generated by something else, simply because the flexibility is there (just as long-form content is becoming more commonplace as CMSs start to deal with it better). For example, using Matrix we can pick and choose which types of content are included within the feed to a much greater degree. Or do we just say, no, a feed should contain this, this and this and you shouldn't mess with that, no matter what the tool?

Comment: Do you want to post the full content to RSS? Do you want to include only select block types? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: What exactly is my problem? Ha. Sure you didn't mean it that way! I'm already using a summary field as the content for each post in the RSS, just like ianisted suggests. I'm curious to know what everyone else does - I've amended the question.

Comment: Huh, isn't it right to ask it like this?

Comment: Ignore me. That's my bad English humour. I'll leave it out.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a lead paragraph field that you could then call into the RSS feed. Or you could add a post summary field. You could then call that whenever you need to, RSS or otherwise.

Comment: Would you include an image? If so, how - in the CDATA or within a logo or icon tag?

Comment: I use the CDATA method. Though some RSS readers might be smart enough to show an image if it is just embedded in the content.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting you right you have no problem with Craft outputting the content you want.

You are rather asking us on what is considered best practice for what content one should deliver with RSS feeds. I'd say it is totally up to you, there's no real standardized way on how to do it right, as far as I can tell. I did have feeds with long read articles and others with just a title / subtitle.

If there is a nice (mobile) site layout (without distracting adds) I always preferred reading the content on the sites themselves. With other feeds I was happy not being forced to use the whole website for their articles.

Comment: Do you include images in the feed?

Comment: Yeah if you send the full content to the feed I think you should definitely include the images.

Comment: @Clive did you ever subscribe to RSS feeds yourself? The above is more written out of a readers perspective then a web designers one.

Comment: I think you're right, I am partly asking about best practice with RSS feeds, but the reason I am asking is because of the extra flexibility of Craft and the fact I'm wondering how other people take advantage of that within RSS feeds. I've edit the question.